# Requisições http usando a linguagem C no windows?

Tags: c, c++, http

Como fazer requisições http usando a linguagem C no windows ? Não precisam postar código, apenas uma boa referencia é o suficiente pra mim :) Mas se alguém tiver algum exemplo será de grande ajuda ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22077802/540552

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar Windows Sockets 2, ou usar Qt que tem uma ampla biblioteca de rede e é multiplataforma